# C-divide input string - segmentation error

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

my code would work in this way:

```
input : a[]="create  /dir/bar"
```

and save in this string:

```
b[]=create
c[]=/dir/bar
```

there is also a case in which i save an other string: (for example)

```
a[]=write /foo/bar  "test"

b[]= write
c[]=/foo/bar
d[]=test   (without the "")
```

my code is this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define SPACE ' '

void divide(char a[], char b[], char c[], char d[]);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char a[50+1];
    char b[50+1];
    char c[50+1];
    char d[50+1];
    int i;

    scanf("%s\n", a);

    divide(a, b, c, d);

    for(i=0; b[i]!='\0'; i++)
        printf("%s %s %s \n", b, c, d);

    return 0;
}



void divide(char a[], char b[], char c[], char d[]){
    int i, j;

    for(i=0; a[i]!=SPACE; i++)
        b[i]=a[i];

    b[i]='\0';

    for(; a[i]==SPACE; i++)
        ;

    for(j=0; a[i]!='\0'; i++, j++)
        c[j]=a[i];

    c[j]='\0';
    for(; a[i]==SPACE; i++)
        ;

    if(a[i]=='"'){
        i++;
        for(j=0; a[i]!='"'; i++)
            d[j]=a[i];

        d[j]='\0';

        return;
    }
}
```

but it does not work for a segmentation fault after the program get the input. where is the problem?

I must not use malloc, because it spend too much time to work (I have to get thousands of these lines) and does not respect a limit. (I work for a project in my university)

Comment: 1) `scanf("%s\n", a);` --> `scanf("%50[^\n]", a);`

Comment: `for(i=0; b[i]!='\0'; i++)` ??

Comment: 2) `for(j=0; a[i]!='\0'; i++, j++)` --> `for(j=0; a[i]!=SPACE; i++, j++)`

Comment: 3) `for(j=0; a[i]!='"'; i++)` --> `for(j=0; a[i]!='"'; i++, j++)`

Comment: 4) It is necessary to initialize in case there is no parameter of `d`.

Comment: Or, initialize all in the beginning, e.g. `char a[50+1] = "";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be making this a little more difficult than it needs to be. Yes, you can tokenize a string by repeated calls to `sscanf` or with repeated reads with `scanf`, but the C library provides a tool to tokenize words from a line of text. Smartly enough named `strtok`.

You simply declare a constant string holding the delimiters you wish to break the words on (e.g. `delims = " \t";` to break the words on space or tab, and then call `strtok (str, delims)` to return the first token (word), and then loop over repeated calls to `strtok (NULL, delims)` to parse the remaining words (or until you reach your max of 3 words).

(**note** the first call to `strtok` uses `str` as the first parameter, while all subsequent calls use `NULL`)

This is a far more flexible way to handle an unknown number of tokens in a string.

Instead of using `a[]`, `b[]`, `c[]`, etc.. consider using just a single `buf[]` to read the line of input into, and then an array of strings to hold the parameters (which allows you to use an *index* variable during your loops over `strtok` to assign and copy the correct string to the associated index).

Don't use `void` as a return in circumstances like this. Why not use a meaningful return (like the number of parameters in the line of text). That way, you know how many were read (or tokenized) in your divide function. Give it a return that can provide useful information, e.g.

```
size_t divide (char *buf, char (*params)[MAXC+1]);
```

Which will now return a `size_t` type containing the number of parameters that result from each call to divide.

Putting it altogether, (and using `fgets` to read the entire line of input), you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAXP = 3, MAXC = 50 };   /* max parameters & chars */

size_t divide (char *buf, char (*params)[MAXC+1]);

int main (void) {

    char buf[MAXC * 4 + 1] = "";
    char params[MAXP][MAXC + 1];    /* array to hold 3 parameters */
    size_t i, len, nparams = 0;

    /* use fgets for line-oriented user input */
    printf ("\nenter commands: ");
    if (!fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    len = strlen (buf);         /* get length */
    if (buf[len - 1] == '\n')   /* validate last char is '\n' */
        buf[--len] = 0;         /* overwrite with nul-terminating char */
    else {                      /* short read -- handle error */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: incomplete input read.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    nparams = divide (buf, params);

    for (i = 0; i < nparams; i++)
        printf ("parameter[%zu] : %s\n", i, params[i]);

    return 0;
}

/* divide using strtok */
size_t divide (char *buf, char (*params)[MAXC+1])
{
    char *delims = " \t",   /* delimiters for strtok */
        *p = buf;           /* pointer to buf */
    size_t n = 0;           /* var to return number of params */

    p = strtok (buf, delims);           /* tokenize fist paramter */

    while (p) { /* now loop until all words exhausted or limit reached */
        strncpy (params[n++], p, MAXC); /* copy token to params array */
        if (n == MAXP)                  /* check if limit reached */
            break;
        p = strtok (NULL, delims);      /* get next token */
    }

    return n;   /* return the number of parameters found */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ /bin/splitparams

enter commands: create  /dir/bar
parameter[0] : create
parameter[1] : /dir/bar

$ ./bin/splitparams

enter commands: write /foo/bar  "test"
parameter[0] : write
parameter[1] : /foo/bar
parameter[2] : "test"
```

Or providing a bunch of extra words (to validate handling of only 3)

```
$ ./bin/splitparams

enter commands: write /foo/bar  "test" and some more stuff
parameter[0] : write
parameter[1] : /foo/bar
parameter[2] : "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run this simple program

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    char a[50+1];

    scanf("%s\n", a);
    printf("|%s|\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

and give the input "create foo", you'll get the output

> |create|

As you can see you only got the first word, i.e. "create", instead of the expected "create foo" as

```
scanf("%s\n", a);
```

will only give the first word. Consequently your `divide` function will fail. Instead of `scanf` you could do

```
fgets(a, 51, stdin);
```

to make sure the whole input is read into array `a`.

In general your program lacks a lot of range checking and input validation. You should add that.

Another problem I see is that in case the input is

```
create  /dir/bar
```

you never initialize the string `d` but you still print it in main. That is undefined behaviour.

Try:

```
char d[50+1];
d[0] = '\0';    // Add this line
```